# How to check a checkbox using hyperlinks?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have got a website with several radiobuttons. Some of them are pre-checked.

```
<input checked="checked" type="radio" id="optionid_31" value="31" name="pid[phases]">
<input type="radio" id="optionid_32" value="32" name="pid[phases]" onchange="fchange()">
<input checked="checked" type="radio" id="optionid_33" value="33" name="pid[current]" onchange="fchange()">
<input type="radio" id="optionid_34" value="34" name="pid[current]" onchange="fchange()">
<input type="radio" id="optionid_35" value="35" name="pid[current]" onchange="fchange()" disabled="">
```

But if the user enters the website by clicking a special hyperlink I want "optionid_32" and "optionid_34" to be checked instead of the pre-checked ones.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Broad flow: 1) Clicking link opens the URL with a query string appended e.g. `check_32=true&check_34=true`; 2) A server-side language, or JavaScript at runtime, picks up these query string arguments and checks the checkboxes. This should give you enough to look into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put some identifying piece of data in the query string for the URL that you put in the link.

Then test for it on the server.

Your name attributes follow the PHP convention for complex data structures, so I'm going to assume you are using that.

```
<input 
    type="radio"
    id="optionid_32"
    value="32" name="pid[phases]"
    onchange="fchange()"
    <?php if ($_GET['pid']['phases'] == 32) { ?>checked<?php } ?>
>
```

NB: This is a simple example, you'll need `isset` to avoid testing things that don't exist, and something to avoid adding the `checked` attribute to the first radio button.